# Need to create leads with or without activities and also show task field in the report

Tags: dashboard, custom-report-type, joined-reports

I need to create a report on Leads with or without activities and also need to show lead task field in the report...

new bee....

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood your question to be, you want to create a new recordtype which includes Leads with or without activities. Then create a new report and add the fields for Leads and Activities to it that you want. Remember, a task is a subset of the Activity object.

1 In setup, do a search for recordtypes
2 Create a new one which is based on Leads and add another object which is the Activity object. 
4 Make sure that you choose the second option ""A" records may or may not have related "B" records.".
5 Go to reports and create a new report.
6 Find the new report type which should be in the Lead folder.
7 You can drag fields from both object to the report which should give you what you want.